# Crazy time format?

Tags: javascript, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have an api return an expire time, which looks like a countdown. Im not familiar with milliseconds or whatever this is. The countdown said this number was around a few minutes. I thought it was a unix time, where you could subtract current time from 1970, then convert to minutes but that is giving me a crazy number..
 What format is this?

`1470041268756`

Comment: It's probably not seconds since the Epoch, but milliseconds since the Epoch.  Try dividing by 1000 before converting the time, and check your API's documentation on units.

Comment: a quick division by 1000 was it. Thnks!

Comment: By the way, if you are concerned about the downvotes for the question, I would recommend you at least include the exact date that this value supposedly represents. Although it is fairly guessable what the format is, you could literally argue it is anything without having a valid target date time

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing crazy about it. Well, nothing beyond *normal* UNIX craziness :-)

If you head on over to the [Unix epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) and plug that value in, you'll see:

```
Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Mon, 01 Aug 2016 08:47:48.756 GMT
```

which is certainly viable in terms of being a few minutes after you formed the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't given much information, I would have to *guess* that it is unix timestamp but in milliseconds. So if you divide by 1000 first (essentially remove the last 3 digits) and then convert you would get the following:

```
Mon, 01 Aug 2016 08:47:48 GMT
```

I would expect you can find a conversion function that works with milliseconds too though. In fact, with javascript the `Date` object will take this format (in milliseconds):

```
var date = new Date(1470041268756);
console.log(date); // Mon Aug 01 2016 09:47:48 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

They look like milliseconds since 01/01/1970 00:00

[see here](http://www.timestampconvert.com/?go2=true&offset=-2&timestamp=1470041268756&Submit=%20%20%20%20%20%20Convert%20to%20Date%20%20%20%20%20%20)

Answer (score -1):

you may use moment.js

```js
alert(moment.unix(1470041268756/1000).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Overkill when JS already provides the functionality by just using `new Date(1470041268756)`